# From one activity to two other

Tags: android, android-activity

Is it possible for one `Activity` to have two others. What I mean is I have 2 buttons for two parent activities - `Button 1` and `Button 2`. When I click on `Button 1` it is opening `activity 1` which also has  `activity 2`. When I click `Button 2` it is opening same `activity 1` like on `Button 1` and here is the catch. I want 3rd activity of button 2 to be different. Currently it opens 3rd activity which is on button 1. I will try to illustrate it

```
Button 1(Activity 1) -> listView (Activity 2) -> TextView (Activity 3)
Button 2(Activity 1) -> listView (Activity 2) -> TextView (Activity 3) <- this must be different from above activity 3
```

I use same Activity 2 for both menu buttons and then activity 3 must be different for both. I cansee from where this problem come. Because second activity on button 2 is the second activity on button 1. But I don't want to make another activity and to load same thing and to duplicate code/activities. Or should I? 
Update:

```
Button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Menu.class);
        intent.putExtra("button", "button1");
        startActivity(intent);

    }
});
Button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Menu.class);
        intent.putExtra("button", "button2");
        startActivity(intent);

    }
});
```

Here is activity 3 for `button1`

```
    @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.act3);

Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
if (b != null) {
    String button = b.getString("button"); 
}
}
```

Here is activity 3 for `button2`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.act3_1);

    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (b != null) {
        String button = b.getString("button"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: You want 3rd activity to be different means two difference activities you have that you will show after activity 2 (depending on from which button you came from) or you have only one activity as activity 3, but you want different UI for each button.

Comment: Yes, I want this `You want 3rd activity to be different means two difference activities you have that you will show after activity 2 (depending on from which button you came from)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this for button 1 `onCLick` :

```
intent.putExtra("button", "button1");
```

For button 2 `onCLick`:

```
intent.putExtra("button", "button2");
```

Pass that value through from `Activity` 1 to `Activity` 3, through `Activity` 2.

In `Activity` 3's `onCreate`, use :

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();

if(b != null)
   String btn = b.getString("button");
```

You can use this `String` to know, whether its from button1 or button2.

Comment: You mean simply to put in each activity 2 this?

Comment: I saw it and going to try this now.

Comment: One little problem. In `Activity 2` I don't have button actually they are listView items.

Comment: Yep, thats what I was talking about.

Comment: I've edited my question. So two buttons which open same activity. And where should I use this `intent.putExtra("button", "button1");` and `intent.putExtra("button", "button2");`

Comment: @Goro in your explanation, you still use intent from Act 2 to Act 3 right? You can put the code in the onListItemClick :)

Comment: Yes, as you can see activity 2 is same for both and then 3 must be different. Ok, so I put in this in `setOnClickListener` in MainActivity for each button? Then in second activity I need to get them both in same `String btn = b.getExtra("button");`? And in 3rd activity which will be different I will  get button1 or 2 only`String btn = b.getExtra("button");`?

Comment: "Then in second activity I need to get them both in same String btn = b.getExtra("button");" No, the value will be only one (either "button1" or "button2"). Later, you pass the value you received to the Act 3

Comment: Well that's what I can't understand. I have only one Activity 2. As I see it I must somehow tell to Activity 2 which button I click from MainActivity? Meaning I must tell to Activity 2 that on MainActivity I have 2 buttons and to 'watch' which one will click from here to activity 3. Or my logic is wrong? If I put only one button as get extra how will know which one is?

Comment: Yes, i understood your question. You pass the value from act 1 to act 2 to act 3...i will try to update my answer so u can understand easier

Comment: Ah, you mean I don't need to put anything in Activity 2? Also when I put in Activity 3 `String btn = b.getExtra("button");` I get `The method getExtra(String) is undefined for the type Bundle`. I've already have there `Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();`

Comment: You just need to pass the value you got to act 3, and sorry i updated my answer :)

Comment: Still open same third activity. I will update my question with what I've made.

Comment: @Goro OK, i need to go for a while, please give your updated code :)

Comment: @Goro See : "String button = b.getString("button1");" change to String button = b.getString("button"); (look at my answer) :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64686/discussion-between-blaze-tama-and-goro).